# Unary operator definitions for custom types in Scala

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, anonymous-function

Tried running this code:

`def ! : Int => Boolean = (p : Int => Boolean) => !p`

Has a compilation error:

```
[error] value unary_! is not a member of Int => Boolean  
[error]   def ! : Int => Boolean = (p : Int => Boolean) => !p
```

error is highlighted for "!p"

Shouldn't the compiler automatically figure out that the result of p is a `Boolean` ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Based on comments, tried the following also. Have accomplished my task using other methods, nonetheless, am trying to learn how to define an unary operator

`def unary_! : Int => Boolean = (p : Int => Boolean) => !(p(_))`

still getting a compiler error at `"!(p(_))"`

Comment: Unary ! for a custom type must be named `unary_!` as in the error. Your `p` takes an `Int`, so `!p(42)`.

Comment: Unary operator for what class?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to accomplish.  Could you be more specific about what you want this to do?

Comment: You're not calling `p`. So the `!` isn't negating the return value of `p`, but `p` itself, and `!` isn't an operator defined for functions.

Comment: For example https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M4/src/library/scala/math/BigInt.scala#L268

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you intend something like:

```
scala> class C(p: Int => Boolean) { def unary_! : Int => Boolean = !p(_) }
defined class C

scala> val c = new C(i => i < 0)
c: C = C@4d9cad9d

scala> (!c)(42)
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Very nice. Thanks much. Will have to figure out why this works & my attempts did not.